# Client Side Validations on Nested Field Not Generate Valiadtion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, client-side-validation

I have application rails and use client_side_validations gem with Devise to validate devise registrations form

//account.rb

```
has_one :user
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

//user.rb

```
 belongs_to :account
 validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

//new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>

   <%= f.fields_for :account, :validate => true do |inner_form|%>
      <div  class="field">
          <%= inner_form.label :username, "Username" %><br />
          <%= inner_form.text_field :username %>
      </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :email, "Email" %>
       <%= f.email_field :email %>
   </div>
   <div>
       <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
   </div>

<% end %>
```

Validations work fine with email field but for username not worked..
help me,,, thanks

**UPDATE** ---validate show but this is no nested form

change :account to @account

```
<%= f.fields_for :account, :validate => true do |inner_form|%>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for @account, :validate => true do |inner_form|%>
```

when submit i get the error
Account(#27129348) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#26695068)

when validates not worked, html code

```
<input id="user_account_attributes_username" name="user[account_attributes][username]" size="30" type="text" data-validate="true">
```

validates worked

```
<input id="user_account_username" name="user[account][username]" size="30" type="text" data-validate="true">
```

issue

user_account_attributes_username

user[account_attributes][username]

worked

user_account_username

user[account][username]

Comment: What didn't work? The validations aren't enforced, or error messages aren't shown?

Comment: I think your main problem is the way you have set up your `<%= f.fields_for :account`. I am certain that you should have it set out like the following `<%= fields_for @account, :validate => true do |inner_form|%>` let me know if this resolves the issue.

Comment: @Andrew no show error message , but validation not generate..

Comment: @user532339 not worked, same issue https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/423

Answer (score 2):

For current `DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations` version (Rails 4.2) fixing nested forms is just replacing line (in `rails.validations.js` or `.coffee` placed inside `validateForm` function):

```
name = name.replace(/\[[\da-z_]+\]\[(\w+)\]$/g, "[][$1]");
```

With some better regexp, which will eliminate every `[ids]` and `[new_ids]` from `name` string. Here is one solution presented on `jeroenj/client_side_validations`:

```
name = name.replace(/\[((?:new_)?\d+|[0-9a-f]{24})\]/g, "[]");
```

It's nice (as long as you have sane attributes names) but probably there are some better ways to do this. If anyone is good at writing JS regexps please help to improve it. I will try as soon as I finish current project but I'm definitely not a regexp master.

#### IMPORTANT:

What is more in current `client_side_validations` version you have to comment out `if(...) { }` which surrounds mentioned regexp instruction. This is just quickfix, `if` is probably necessary at some point but I didn't find any usage for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

We found this branch which solved that problem.

I just updated my Gemfile with this line:

```
gem 'client_side_validations', github: "jeroenj/client_side_validations", :branch => "4-0-deeply-nested-forms"
```

Hope that work for you